# sign in with google account in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Right now i am using this example in the url http://www.dotnetethics.com/2008/09/signin-using-google-account.html   to sign in to my website using google account. This example uses the url http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts .

Is there any other way to sign in via google account other than using contact feed. Please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Google supports OpenID.  Try out DotNetOpenAuth.

http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/